# Como consigo la URL cuando le doy click en enlace en un WebView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Aqui remito parte del codigo, que esta realizando: tengo un EditText para que el usuario busque una 
 url, tengo un imageBotton para busqueda y un WebView; estoy necesitando conseguir la URL cuando le 
 dan click a otro enlace en la webview y posteriormente hacer trabajar al WebWiew en segundo plano; 
 pero no logro conseguir la URL.

```
    public EditText et_search_youtube2;
    private ImageButton img_boton_search_youtube2;
    private WebView wv2;
    String txt_web, url_usuario;
    String url_string;


       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_karaoke);

       wv2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_video_karaoke2);
       wv2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       wv2.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
       wv2.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

       wv2.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
       }



       private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

       @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            url_string = url;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onPageFinished: " + url_string, 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

         @Override
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             //view.loadUrl(url_string);
             //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "shouldOverrideUrlLoading " + url_string, 
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);

         }


     public void Buscar_youtube (View view) {
     txt_web = et_search_youtube2.getText().toString();
     url_usuario = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + txt_web;
     wv2.loadUrl(url_usuario);
     et_search_youtube2.setText("");
     }
```

Comment: En que lenguaje estas trabajando? las etiquetas no deben ser url - webview, porque no se busca url para buscar una solucion de algo. ya que url tienen todos los lenguajes y diversos problemas. Coloca como etiqueta el lenguaje, el IDE que trabajas, etc

Comment: estoy trabajando en java, para Android Estudio android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.karaokeplay"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes realizar usando un `WebViewClient` de hecho veo que es lo que tratas, la url a la que des click dentro del WebView la puedes obtener dentro del método:

```
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){

            //url contiene el valor de la url a la que te llevar el click.
            System.out.println("La url es: " + url); 

            return false; 
        }
```

Comment: Si ya intente; cada vez que le doy clic a un enlace nuevo en el WebView, no me arroja directamente la URL en el código que mencionas. Cuando lo realizo en el  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url), se logro obtener la URL, pero siempre tengo que hacer un reload; no se como hacer que me lo arroje directamente